# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/.aws/credentials' when run up on Docker Container

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, docker

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDbhu.png)

When run app locally it run normally but when i try to run app docker container i receive this error like on screen
Its my Docker file:

```
FROM node:14.0.0
WORKDIR /app
ARG DATABASE_URL
ARG AWS_REGION
ARG CLIENT_ID
ARG USER_POOL_ID
ARG AWS_IOT_PUBLIC_TOPIC_NAME
ARG AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
ARG AWS_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY_ID
ARG AWS_ELASTIC_SERVICE_URL
ARG PORT
ARG IDENTIFY_POOL_ID
ARG MQTT_ENDPOINT

COPY package.json package-lock.json* ./
RUN npm install
COPY . /app

ENV DATABASE_URL=$DATABASE_URL
ENV REGION=$AWS_REGION
ENV CLIENT_ID=$CLIENT_ID
ENV USER_POOL_ID=$USER_POOL_ID
ENV AWS_IOT_PUBLIC_TOPIC_NAME=$AWS_IOT_PUBLIC_TOPIC_NAME
ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
ENV AWS_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY_ID
ENV AWS_ELASTIC_SERVICE_URL=$AWS_ELASTIC_SERVICE_URL
ENV PORT=$PORT
ENV IDENTIFY_POOL_ID=$IDENTIFY_POOL_ID
ENV MQTT_ENDPOINT=$MQTT_ENDPOINT

RUN printenv

EXPOSE 5001
CMD npm run start
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by bind-mounting your credentials file into the container:

```
docker run -v $HOME/.aws:/root/.aws ...
```

I don't like doing this, because it means that something inside the container can change files in your directory in ways that you might not expect (and making them owned by root).

I prefer instead using environment variables to hold my credentials, and passing them to Docker using `-e`:

```
docker run -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY -e AWS_DEFAULT_REGION -e AWS_REGION ...
```

Note that these variables must already be defined in your environment to be passed as `-e VARNAME` (and you shouldn't use `-e VARNAME=VALUE` because that makes the keys visible with `ps`).

Comment: (Do NOT put credentials in your Dockerfile: they're trivially extracted with `docker inspect` or `docker history`.)

Comment: @DavidMaze - I did not suggest putting credentials in the Dockerfile.

Comment: That comment was directed more at the original asker.  If I `docker inspect their-image | grep AWS` the credentials will be there for all to see.  Passing them in via environment variables as you suggest, or relying on the EC2 metadata service http://169.254.169.254, are both better approaches.

Comment: Ah, OK ... tbh, I didn't look at their Dockerfile, and assumed that they just weren't providing credentials. Now that I've taken a look, the problem is that they misspelled one of the environment variables. But your comment is a good one, and worth adding to the question itself.